Seemingly random runtime '4605' error when copying data from excel to word
I am writing a Macro that is supposed to crate word quotations based on a selection of text modules made in Excel. Since the number of cells that are supposed to be copied can vary the code has a loop that copies the data, then changes a couple of variables in the excel sheet, then checks if it still has to copy data, and repeats this process endlessly until all data is copied. I don’t know if there might be an more elegant way to do this process, but this loop does the job. The problem is a runtime 4605 error that sometimes appears when data should be pasted into the word. What makes this error so confusing is that it does not appear consistently. I run the code one time, and it crashes. I run it again with the same selection of text modules and it works fine or sometimes it just crashes while pasting a different block of text. The error massage also says that the paste method for the object selection has failed. I am manly asking for an explanation of the Runtime error, since I don’t think that there is something wrong with my code, but I include it anyway, maybe someone can spot something that explains this behavior. I am not very experienced with VBA, so I am sorry if there is some obvious mistake, but I couldn’t find any solution or explanation to my problem anywhere else.
Option Explicit

Sub CreateQuotation()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wks1, wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim CopL, LCounter, LEnd, AMachine, PMachine As Integer
    
    Set wks1 = Sheets("DocumentExtractor")
    Set wks2 = Sheets("Quotation")

    wks1.Cells(11, 65) = 1

    wks1.Calculate
    wks2.Calculate
    
    LCounter = 22
    
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        .Documents.Add "'path to template"
        .Selection.GoTo -1, , , "ScopeOfSupply"
        
    End With
    
    
    AMachine = wks1.Cells(11, 65)
    
    Do
        
        wks2.Calculate
        wks2.Range("G9:J11").Copy
        wdApp.Selection.Paste
    
        Do
    
            CopL = wks1.Cells(LCounter, 53)
    
            wks2.Range("G" & CopL & ":J" & CopL).Copy
            wdApp.Selection.Paste '<--------------------- this is where the error occurs
        
            PMachine = wks1.Cells(LCounter + 1, 47)
            LCounter = LCounter + 1
            
            
        Loop While AMachine = PMachine
        
        AMachine = AMachine + 1
        wks1.Cells(11, 65) = AMachine
               
    
    Loop While AMachine <= wks1.Cells(14, 65)
        
    wks1.Cells(11, 65) = 1

End Sub


Welcome to the board! Have you tried google? Link for example?  (not that familiar with VBA myself)

@Excellor I've googled the problem before but didn't find the thread you linked. I added the “DoEvents” line as described in the thread and my code now works fine. Thank you!
